# How to verify requests in backend

Tags: android, security, android-security, rest-security

I'm creating a payment android library(`aar`) and i have to make sure that all of the requests that i got in `back-end` are from my lib not a fake lib.

how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

I used two ways before:

1- Easy and bad way: Try to use a hardcoded String like JWT in your app and use a strong obfuscator to avoid decompiling the application.

2- Better way: You can use `instance id` and send it to your backend and server can inquire this id from the Google and there are some elements like `package id` in the response which server can use to accept or reject the request.

A sample response from the Google:

```
{
  "application":"com.iid.example",
  "authorizedEntity":"123456782354",
  "platform":"Android",
  "attestStatus":"ROOTED",
  "appSigner":"1a2bc3d4e5",
  "connectionType":"WIFI",
  "connectDate":"2015-05-12
  }
}
```

reference: https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server

Comment: so where should i save `MY_API_KEY`? if found, the fake lib can generate valid `instance id` and my `back-end` will accept the request

Comment: API_KEY is in your backend not mobile.